# Low intensity UV light detector

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, light-sensor, detector

I wanted to build low light UV detector, I mean the measurement of light with wavelength 405 nm. I found two schemes:

First circuit:

[image: First]

And the second circuit:

[image: Second]

I wanted to use operational amplifier TLE2072CP and diode BPW21R. The bandwidth doesn't matter because I'll be observing light intensity which is DC level output voltage.

I wanted to use second op amp in TLE2072CP as non-inverting amplifier for additional signal amplification.

The circuit will be in shielding box, I assume in the second circuit, ground should be connected to shielding box, but I don't know what should be connected to shielding box in the first circuit.

Which of these two schemes will be better for my application?

Edit:

Due to your suggestions, I've tried to plot second circuit: [mycircuit link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKABZJjwNDvfc2fcFGi8qMSCmwRILAO4gUHcG0FKqxMfMXLNivHhB7ZAc32G9KA%20CtQo2sKvCEqYHs-HaBQ7AhRDZBUdBMBcVEK0AJ3DnEF9-ULsweHgvP1j4gIcnROCQBkJBWQBjGILBTPK7Qmg8FPr6%20gYucVhIVgVKwrj0xMChMGJ-OvAh%20wURweGqb1loke91OMgi8G0ltEMl2ZZ5mZWQEbZu120j7qXjopYANx19tWUruyplMCRxEQQWM0uL5QQYH8ngmDzsO1BIGerxOLFKYJhqxkIjgrA4XA4rjGfkMUziIjEKKkyQaDWB2kxPl67n6lM2PX89P6mXpmR20TZBxxyyRDW03Lx3IhFFseMIGASY36kzGTHceJK%20TcvDxcv42EJYGgKEYLRR7W0atG-gYKAQKqlhuVcQ1%20TN6q0AEs7ebjS6HS9YKwzEbsLbfXhVnMGTyQ9DkHA0v5nn9rkA).

Some values and components are missing, how the circuit should look like?

Comment: Have you considered an optical (UV band pass) filter?  After that it should be a matter of amplification and calibration.

Comment: The BPW21R is not sensitive to UV. It has been specifically constructed to be sensitive only to visible wavelengths as much as possible. Even it's unfiltered cousin, the BPW20R is not sensitive to UV due to the window material. Right now, GenUV available from Digikey seems to have the most easily available UV selective photodioes so no visible or NIR filters are required (which also oxidize from atmospheric moisture) which cuts down on cost a lot. The photodiodes can still be quite pricey though depending on the area you choose. From 2-5x the cost of your BPW21R with less active area.

Comment: Those are both essentially the same circuit. The 1st one goes to a little more effort to split the supply rail to supply to the opamp's non-inverting input, but that's really the only difference between them.

Comment: What kind of UV light source are you expecting to measure?   Many such sources are modulated,not nice and constant, because gas discharge isn't a stable process.

Comment: The two circuits are electrically the same ... except for the reference point on BNC in the first (floating center point "not related" to the power supply). Note also that OPAMP decoupling capacitor not present ...

Comment: Both circuits are _not_ the same. The first one has no bias voltage across the detector and uses forward mode, the second one has VCC/2 as bias at the detector and uses reverse mode.

Comment: Right. Ok. I missed that detail. I was only "busy" with the "ground" wiring and "shielding".

Comment: @Jens Is there an advantage of using reserve mode with bias, i. e. second circuit?

Comment: See this question on reverse biasing photodiodes: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409733/why-is-this-photodiode-operated-in-reverse-bias

Comment: Reverse mode can be more sensitive in my experience and is faster if you transport data, because the sensor diode capacitance is lower.

Comment: I've added a circuit scheme link in the post. I'll appreciate your suggestions about values and connections between elements.